# How would I program my code to start over if a certain condition is met?

Tags: c#

For clarification I'm using Microsoft visual studio and trying to turn the cmd format into a cute little interactive terminal. I'm a bare basics beginner and I'm aware this may be an ambitious project for someone of my skill. The only thing I'm confused about at the moment is how to tell the program that I want it to start itself over within the constraints of an else if statement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("What's your age?");
            string age = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name + " and you are " + age + " years old, Correct?");
            string val = Console.ReadLine();
            if (val == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data confirmed, thank you for your cooperation!");
            }
            else if (val == "no")
            {       //I would like to restart the code if this condition is met
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect data provided, please try again");
            }
            else
            {       //The issue with this line is that I want it to just ask if the data is correct again
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid response, try answering with a yes or no");
            }
```

Comment: Use do while loop for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Basically, you're wrapping your code in a loop (in this case, a "do...while" loop, and adding a flag indicating whether or not the program should "start over."

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool finished;

    do
    {
        finished = true;
        Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("What's your age?");
        string age = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name + " and you are " + age + " years old, Correct?");
        string val = Console.ReadLine();
        while(val != "yes" && val != "no") {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid response, try answering with a yes or no");
            val = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (val == "yes") {
            Console.WriteLine("Data confirmed, thank you for your cooperation!");
        }
        else if (val == "no") {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect data provided, please try again");
            finished = false;
        }
    } while(!finished);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I was able to tamper with my code and used that same method to solve the other issue I had of wanting to make the code ask the user if the information is correct again after they type something other than yes or no. However I did use the same method within the other one, if you have any recommendations to make it simpler it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dioqboom I updated my answer with a much simpler version that appears to work. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/dsEqoS for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your code out into a separate method, and call it from your Main() method. Then, in your else statement, you can have your new method call itself so that it executes again. (Disclaimer: It's been a long time since I've written C#.)

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  askName();
}

static void askName() {
  Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
  string name = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
  Console.WriteLine("What's your age?");
  string age = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + name + " and you are " + age + " years old, Correct?");
  string val = Console.ReadLine();

  if (val == "yes") {
    Console.WriteLine("Data confirmed, thank you for your cooperation!");
  } else  if (val == "no") {
    askName();
  } else {
    //The issue with this line is that I want it to just ask if the data is correct again
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid response, try answering with a yes or no");
  }
}
```